# WinAmp not loading new mp3 files

Tags: mp3, winamp

I have some new music on my SD card and Winamp it's not showing it. How can I load the new files.

Comment: By fixing the issue. Honestly, we need some more details – as it stands currently, it's hard to tell anything. Where did you place the new files? Does any of the folders contain a `.nomedia` file? How did you copy the files there? Has the media scanner been run after the copy? Do the files show up with other music players?

Comment: I created a folder named **Music** and there i put the mp3 files. Last time Winamp didn't show any artist/album.

Comment: OK, so what about the other details? HOW did you put the files there (describe the steps), is there any `.nomedia` file, are the files shown by other players?

Comment: i just opened winamp, after ~1 day and it displays the songs

Comment: i plugged the usb cable and copied the files on the sd card

Comment: And for that the device used MTP I guess; would it have used UMS (USB mass storage), the media scanner would have updated everything automatically as soon as you disconnected your device from the computer, and the SDCard was available locally again. // But as we finally figured out, hopefully, I hope my answer is useful to you and able to solve the issue. If so, you might wish to indicate this by "accepting" it (clicking the checkmark next to it). Good luck, and enjoy your music! Glad it finally showed up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the information wormed out by the comments, the culprit seems to lie in the way the files have been transfered – as the transfer method chosen obviously didn't trigger the media scanner.

**Explanation:** Most media players rely on the media database (a SQLite database) to find available tracks, as a simple database query is both faster and less battery consuming than scanning all available storage. Hence the latter is left to a single app, the so-called *Media Scanner*. Once triggered, it scans all available storage and feeds its finds to the SQLite database. This *Media Scanner* is triggered by different events: following a device boot (`boot_completed`), mounting a storage (e.g. putting in a SDCard), and unmounting from *USB Mass Storage* are some examples. So if the files were copied e.g. via some WiFi app, and the *Media Scanner* had not explicitly been triggered, those players won't find the new files.

**Work arounds** you can assume from the explanation: umount/mount the SDCard, or reboot the device. Both not really elegant. Alternatively, check the Playstore for some helpers like [SDrescan](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sdrescan/com.bero.sdrescan), [Media Scanner](http://www.appbrain.com/app/media-scanner/com.clypher.mediascanner), or [Rescan Media](http://www.appbrain.com/app/rescan-media/com.addz.mediascanner), which are simply triggering the *Media Scanner* when you tap their Widgets.