# Why I can't see all images in the gallery?

Tags: gallery

My Phone is SYMPHONY Xplorer W35. Android version JellyBean 4.1.1 Recently I'm facing a problem. Sometimes I download images from my PC to my mobile phone. But unfortunately these images are not in the gallery apps. For this when I need to upload an image from messenger I can't upload them because they are not in the gallery. But after few times the images are automatically shown in the gallery. (My messenger doesn't support uploading file from file manager)

Comment: What gallery app is opening to send the picture? Is it 'Photos' by any chance (the Google one)? That only shows a few recent ones unless you change what tab you are on, or select "Gallery" from the left hand 'hamburger' menu.

Comment: @RossC The question clearly states the "Gallery" app, which is part of Android for a long time. The "Photos" app is not the app in question.

Comment: @PJBrunet yep but it isn't anymore, Google have been chopping and canging for a while. He said "gallery appS" so I presumed there was more than one from that, and wanted to clarify. Many, many devices change the names/convention/code of their own gallery. It's worth asking.

Comment: @RossC I have Android Lollipop and use Gallery exclusively and Photos is not even installed on my phone by default. I'm not rooted. I found this question because it's ranked in Google for "Android Gallery" which is exactly what I wanted help with. Anyway, I see your point. FWIW, there are some good answers here but I ended up using "Total Commander" because Gallery wasn't finding the image on my sdcard.

Answer (score 2):

This very much depends on [how you upload the images to the device](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/54908/16575). In order for the gallery app to pick them up, they must be added to the "media library", which is the job of the [media-scanner](/questions/tagged/media-scanner). So that one needs to run after you've uploaded the image(s).

There are quite a few events triggering the media scanner to do its job – but e.g. uploading a file via FTP, or copying it with a file manager do not belong to that category. Things you can do to trigger it include:

- rebooting the device (media-scanner always runs at `BOOT_COMPLETED`)
- unmount and mount your SD card (it also runs whenever a new medium is attached)
- [trigger a media scan via the the command line](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/51784/16575)
- use a [media scanner trigger app](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/mediascanner) to trigger a scan manually

Pick your choice depending on how often you need to do that. If it happens once a year, a reboot probably is the easiest approach. If you need it daily, one of those apps will be the better solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a file in the folder with the images not visible called ".nomedia". The file, by existing, tells the android system to not include the images in the folder in the media scan. That means that many gallery apps won't see the images. If you have a file manager installed, and know what folder the image is in, you can navigate to the folder and remove the ".nomedia" file. If there is no such file but you manage to find the image it might be another problem.

Comment: No its not like that. I can't find any .nomedia file. The images I can't see are visible in the gallery app but it takes time.. I can't measure how much time it needs. Sometimes after a day I can see the images. Again sometimes after few minutes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you delete .nomedia files & if you still cant view those pictures, you need to rename the folder e.g. from DCIM to DCIM2. Once you can view them on gallery, you can rename back to original folder name e.g. DCIM2 to DCIM. same goes to other folders. Tq

Comment: Why should that be necessary? Once the `.nomedia` files have been removed, one only needs to trigger the [media-scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) – either using an app, or by simply rebooting the device.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a completely different phone and version of Android, but both the issue and the explanation can be universal.  In my case, it was the existence of the `.nomedia` file in the directory I was trying to see in the Gallery app.  This is documented in the Android Developer documentation under [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#SavingSharedFiles) and, as of this writing appears in a sidebar as follows:

> **Hiding your files from the Media Scanner**
>
> Include an empty file named .nomedia in your external files directory (note the dot prefix in the filename). This prevents media scanner from reading your media files and providing them to other apps through the MediaStore content provider.

In my case, some application that I installed must have put this file in my Download directory, hiding all of the images there from the Gallery app (and others as well).

**Solution**: All I had to do was delete the `.nomedia` file from the directory and the contents became visible in the Gallery app.  You can simply connect your phone to your computer and browse to the directory to accomplish this, or use a file manager on your phone configured to view hidden dot files.